# Conflicting names in Python namespace plugins

Tags: pip, setuptools, python-packaging, namespace-package

I'm following the plugins packaging [guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/#using-namespace-packages), using the 'namespace packages' approach.
I've written two plugins, with the following structure:

```
plugin_1
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.py
└── myapp
    └── plugins
        └── plugin_1.py

plugin_2
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.py
└── myapp
    └── plugins
        └── plugin_2.py
```

This works as long the the actual plugins file names are different - pip copies both files (`plugin_1.py`, `plugin_2.py`) to `venv\Lib\site-packages\myapp\plugins\`, where they live side-by-side.

However, if the file names are identical, pip will happily overwrite the first plugin which was installed. Since I do not have control over plugin writers, this could lead to serious problems.

Is there a way to mitigate this, or at least make pip fail in such cases?

Comment: The content of the guide linked seems a bit strange to me, surprising. My recommendation would rather be to do something like this `myapp/plugins/plugin1/__init__.py` and `myapp/plugins/plugin2/__init__.py`, where `myapp` and `myapp/plugins` should always be free of any file (only sub-directories, i.e. only sub-packages).

Comment: @sinoroc - tried it, but if the name of the plugin folder is the same (i.e. instead of plugin1, plugin2 you have my_plugin), the __init__.py file inside it gets overwritten.

Comment: OK, but why would you do that? Of course pip will overwrite. I really recommend you to follow the pattern I mentioned. Each plugin should have its own dedicated sub-package: `myapp.plugins.plugin1` and `myapp.plugins.plugin2`, and make sure that `myapp` and `myapp.plugins` do not contain any file at all (only subdirectories). This is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Okay, I re-read your question and I realize I was focusing on the wrong aspect. You are asking how to prevent "bad" plugin authors to write a plugin that clashes with an already existing plugin. My bad... -- In short, I think that it is not possible, we have to assume the community works in respect of each other. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4625

Comment: Also, as far as I know, this is a problem that is not specific to namespace packages, pip will overwrite any file (I think, I did not check).

Comment: FYI: There is an open issue about this subject on github: [pip overwrites existing files unconditionally during installation #4625](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4625)